# How to make falloff of point light constant using python API

Tags: python, light

Version: Blender 2.81

I want to make point light's falloff_type constant using python api.
And I ran below scripts:

```
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT')
bpy.context.active_object.data.falloff_type = 'CONSTANT'
```

But the second line doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

Comment: I guess that's from an old script right? If so, there is no falloff type attribute anymore as of Blender 2.8x. You would have to create a node tree and use the light falloff node: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/light_falloff.html